# Pivot on Percentile value

Tags: python, pandas

I have three column in my data. Event( a,b,c,d..), Cloudcover(range of value between 0 to 1 and precipIntensity(indicates the intensity in Inches) .

Output: A Table with **Percentile range for ClourCover and precipIntensity** (row and column)  and all events in each corresponding cells

```
Actual Data     
Event    cloudCover    precipIntensity
a          0.52     0
a          0.55     0
a          0.22     0
b          0.9      0
a          0.54     0
c          0.49     0
a          0.46     0
b          0.68     0.0005
a          0.49     0.0001
d          0.86     0.0122
d          1        0.053
a          0.81     0.0002
c          0.09     0
a          0.65     0.0003
b          0.96     0.0002
a          0.66     0
c          0.01     0.0001


Expected Output(**Results below is just to for visualizaion, just to show what exactly will be in output table. The events reflecting may not be correct)                       


                                   precipIntensity_in_%Tile                 
Cloudcover(in%Tile)     0to25   25to50   50to75   75to90   90to95   >95
0_to_25                 a,b       a        b        d        c       d
25_to_50                 b        d        a       c,d       c       b
50_to 75                 so on for others                       
75 to 90                        
90 to 95                        
>95
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide evidence of what you have tried and researched so far and why it didn't work so we can help.

Comment: Can you explain more how is converted `precipIntensity` column to bins `0to25   25to50   50to75   75to90   90to95   >95` ? Because there are values in `inch` and how is created percentages? What is formula? Like `df['p'] = df['precipIntensity'].div(df.groupby('Event')['precipIntensity'].transform('sum'))` ? Or `df['p'] = df['precipIntensity'].div(df['precipIntensity'].sum())` ?

Comment: 0to25 is Percentile bucket for both variables(CloudCover and precipIntensity).

Comment: Eg. If 25th Percentile for .CloudCover' is 0.7, So the bucket of CloudCover for Perentile 0to25 will have all events(like a or b or both ab) whose cloudcover value is between 0 to 0.7

Comment: @Ashi - Yes, for `cloudCover` is is clear, because values between `0 to 1`. But not clear for `precipIntensity`, because there are all values very small, so how are created all groups from sample data?

Comment: Yes Jezreal, you are correct. If the vlues are very small so ...either we can take a heigher percentile range (ie 80-90,90-95,95-99 and >99)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using [pd.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
df[['cloudCover', 'precipIntensity']]  = df[['cloudCover', 'precipIntensity']].apply(lambda x: pd.cut(x,
                                                                                                      [0, .25, .5, .75, .9, .95, 1],
                                                                                                      include_lowest=True))

   Event      cloudCover precipIntensity
0      a     (0.5, 0.75]  (-0.001, 0.25]
1      a     (0.5, 0.75]  (-0.001, 0.25]
2      a  (-0.001, 0.25]  (-0.001, 0.25]
3      b     (0.75, 0.9]  (-0.001, 0.25]
4      a     (0.5, 0.75]  (-0.001, 0.25]
5      c     (0.25, 0.5]  (-0.001, 0.25]
6      a     (0.25, 0.5]  (-0.001, 0.25]
7      b     (0.5, 0.75]  (-0.001, 0.25]
8      a     (0.25, 0.5]  (-0.001, 0.25]
9      d     (0.75, 0.9]  (-0.001, 0.25]
10     d     (0.95, 1.0]  (-0.001, 0.25]
11     a     (0.75, 0.9]  (-0.001, 0.25]
12     c  (-0.001, 0.25]  (-0.001, 0.25]
13     a     (0.5, 0.75]  (-0.001, 0.25]
14     b     (0.95, 1.0]  (-0.001, 0.25]
15     a     (0.5, 0.75]  (-0.001, 0.25]
16     c  (-0.001, 0.25]  (-0.001, 0.25]
```

Then follow it up with [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df.groupby(['cloudCover', 'precipIntensity'])['Event']
  .apply(set)
  .reset_index()
  .pivot(index='cloudCover',
         columns='precipIntensity',
         values='Event')

precipIntensity (-0.001, 0.25]
cloudCover                    
(-0.001, 0.25]          {c, a}
(0.25, 0.5]             {c, a}
(0.5, 0.75]             {a, b}
(0.75, 0.9]          {a, d, b}
(0.95, 1.0]             {d, b}
```

Comment: Hi Zipa, why precipIntensity is not appearing for all percentile, only 1 bucket ie 0-25 percentile is reflecting.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
bins= [ 0, 25, 50, 75, 90, 95, np.inf]
labels = ['{} to {}'.format(i, j) for i, j in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])] 
labels[-1] = '>95'

df['cloudCover'] = pd.cut(df['cloudCover'] * 100, bins, 
                          include_lowest=True, labels=labels)
df['precipIntensity'] = pd.cut(df['precipIntensity'] * 100, bins, 
                               include_lowest=True, labels=labels)


df1 = (df.drop_duplicates(['Event','cloudCover','precipIntensity'])
        .pivot_table(index='cloudCover',
                     columns='precipIntensity',
                     values='Event', aggfunc=', '.join))
print (df1)
precipIntensity  0 to 25
cloudCover              
0 to 25             a, c
25 to 50            c, a
50 to 75            a, b
75 to 90         b, d, a
>95                 d, b
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael, Thanks a lot . I have one question. Why there is only one bucket(0 to 25) for precipIntensity. It sould be more like 25 to 50, 50 to 75 and so on

Comment: @Ashi This is exactly what I ask under question in comments. So need to explain it.

Comment: ok, actually I need All Percentile for both variables(cloud cover and precipIntensity). As of now CloudCover is file but precipIntensity should also have all percentile